# Create extension using pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have used pgAdmin3 in the past and when creating an extension there is a drop down list of available extensions. In pgAdmin4 the list is empty.

I thought that maybe I had to begin typing an extension name to get a list of results, but to no avail.

TIA for help!

Comment: do you have contrib installed?.. or you mean with same server pgadmin II and IV behaves differently?..

Comment: You nailed it! I forgot to install contrib. My comparison between pgAdmin 3 and pgAdmin 4 was between different servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not check it myself, but the first thing that comes to my mind is - `contrib` package is not installed. So the difference is not between PgAdminIII and PgAdmin4, but rather between Postgrgres installations